# c# write results in console form

Tags: console

I have a windows form and I have a textbox on it and user will write a number in that and I want to do some calculation on that number. My form is like this:

http://8pic.ir/images/fsyg31jcfm7rs69yejfy.png

If one of those radio button is checked ***AFTER*** clicking on the button I want to show a console and write my math calculation step by step on that.
What should I do?
(As I said I want to show the console after clicking on the button not before that by choosing console application on output in project -> properties )
Thanks.

Comment: I would create another window with a textbox that fills the entire window and format it white-on-black so it _looks_ like a console window.  It will be a lot easier to work with.

Comment: Try this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1000be08-107b-4941-aa95-26e2fcb4b06b/embed-cmd-prompt-in-panel-or-mdi-container